# Triangle-ish Number Series

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Before I grind some algebra I was wondering if there was a known equation for a series of the form:

$$(x-y)+(x-2y)+(x-3y)+\dots+(x-ny) = T$$

Also a variant:

$$T-(q+y)-(q+2y)-(q+3y)-\dots-(q+ny) = 0$$

The first goes from $0$ to $T$ and the second from $T$ to $0$.

$x$, $y$, and $T$ are known for each instance, but change with each instance.

Comment: These are sums of arithmetic progressions, so yes, there are standard formulas.

Comment: $T$ is not the same in those two expressions, and if they are then $q=x-(n+1)y$

Answer (score 3):

**Answer changed to match corrected problem statement:**

It really does just require knowledge of the formula for the triangular numbers:

$$\begin{align*}
(x-y)+(x-2y)+\ldots+(x-ny)&=nx-y(1+2+\ldots+n)\\
&=nx-y\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}2\\
&=n\left(x-\frac{n+1}2y\right)\;,
\end{align*}$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
T-(q+y)-(q+2y)-\ldots-(q+ny)&=T-\Big(nq+y(1+2+\ldots+n)\Big)\\
&=T-\Big(nq+y\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}2\Big)\\
&=T-n\left(q+\frac{n+1}2y\right)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Bah, went ahead and ground it out...

First...

$(nx)-((y)*(((n)*(n-1))/2))$

Second...

$T-(nq)-((y)*((n*(n-1))/2))$

Comment: @Char: That should be $(n-1)x$ in the first and $(n-1)q$ in the second.

Comment: When I plug the numbers I get the results I am looking for without your (n-1) edits?  Plus your eq gives unequal solutions for the same values.  Try, T=900, x=380/3, and y=20/3,q=220/3.

Comment: @Char: Sorry, that was a typo: those should have been $n+1$, as in my answer. If you used $nx$ in the first one, you got the wrong answer: there are $n+1$ $x$ terms, not $n$ of them.

Comment: You try the values I suggested?

Comment: (n+1) in the first returns $T+x$, and in the second returns $-q$

Comment: @Char: I don't have to try any numerical values: the algebra is entirely unambiguous. If you're getting something other than $(n+1)\left(x-\frac{n}2y\right)$ for the first and $T-(n+1)\left(q-\frac{n}2y\right)$ for the second, you're not calculating the expressions that you gave in the question.

Comment: My bad, a typo in the question I failed to notice...